# How to use bigquery correlation based on many columns?

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a dataset of 100k rows and 100 columns, how is it possible to use bigquery CORR() to find the correlation between the rows?

The schema is:

```
id:integer, feature1:float, feature2:float, ..., feature100:float
```

**Edit** This is not a rolling window time series correlation problem. Each row is an observation of 100 features, and I'd like to use bigquery to find the top N similar observations for each row.

Comment: Time it takes is to excute corr() within BQ ridiculous slow IMO.  I wouldn't take this route,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to find the correlation between each column and the other columns?

That would be something like this:

```
SELECT CORR(col1, col2), CORR(col1, col3), CORR(col1, col4),..., CORR(col99, col100)
FROM [mytable]
```

That might take a long time to write (unless you automate it). As an alternative, consider a different schema where everything lives in 3 columns. The transformation would run like this:

```
SELECT colname, value, rowid FROM
(SELECT 'col1' AS colname, col1, rowid AS value FROM [mytable]),
(SELECT 'col2' AS colname, col2, rowid AS value FROM [mytable]),
(SELECT 'col3' AS colname, col3, rowid AS value FROM [mytable]),
...
(SELECT 'col100' AS colname, col100 AS value FROM [mytable])
```

With this schema you can run all the combined column correlations with a simpler query:

```
SELECT CORR(a.value, b.value) corr, a.colname, b.colname
FROM [my_new_table] a
JOIN EACH [my_new_table] b
ON a.rowid=b.rowid
WHERE a.colname>b.colname
GROUP BY a.colname, b.colname
```

(That's what I did on the article linked by @Tjorriemorrie - http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.mx/2013/09/introducing-corr-to-google-bigquery.html)

Note that the first query might be more complex that this last one, but I suspect it will take less time to run, as no shuffling will be required.

Since this question asks about rows, the initial transformation would be similar, but slightly different:

```
SELECT column, value, rowid FROM
  (SELECT 'c1' column, c1 AS value, rowid FROM [mytable]),
  (SELECT 'c2' column, c2 AS value, rowid FROM [mytable]),
  (SELECT 'c3' column, c3 AS value, rowid FROM [mytable])
```

Then the correlation between rows would be computed as in:

```
SELECT CORR(a.value, b.value), a.rowid, b.rowid
FROM [my_new_table] a
JOIN EACH [my_new_table] b
ON a.column=b.column
WHERE a.rowid < b.rowid
GROUP BY a.rowid, b.rowid
```

Comment: No, I want to find the correlation of each row, to other (100k - 1) rows, but only keep the top N correlations for each row.

Comment: Right. See updated answer - same philosophy, generating a table based on the original rows instead of columns. Self contained gist I used to try this https://gist.github.com/fhoffa/411cd5ac0d7b8bd2b17a (it's always better if you have a public available table I can use to try queries out - the gist is ugly as it generates a table manually repeated times)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - The solution from gist yields ambiguous 'c' variable.

Answer (score 0):

For the aggregate function:

```
CORR(numeric_expr, numeric_expr)    Returns the Pearson correlation coefficient of a set of number pairs.
```

I would recommend you look at the blog post:
http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/09/introducing-corr-to-google-bigquery.html

```
SELECT CORR(a.data, b.data) corr, a.room room, count(*) c
FROM (
  SELECT
    TIME(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(INTEGER(Timestamp / 60000000) * 60000000)) time, AVG(DATA) data, room
  FROM [io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
  WHERE
    DATE(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp- 8*60*60000000)) = '2013-05-16'
    AND sensortype='temperature'
    GROUP EACH BY time, room) a
JOIN EACH (
  SELECT
    TIME(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(INTEGER(Timestamp / 60000000) * 60000000)) time, AVG(data) data, room
  FROM [io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
  WHERE
    DATE(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp- 8*60*60000000)) = '2013-05-17'
    AND sensortype='temperature'
    GROUP EACH BY time, room) b
  ON a.time=b.time AND a.room = b.room
  GROUP EACH BY room
HAVING
  corr IS NOT NULL
  AND c > 800
  ORDER EACH BY corr DESC
```

It seems you set the `a` with a subselect and `b` with a join, with the help of the `where` clause. I don't know over what values/timeframe you wish to do the correlation, but you should be able to then construct it accordingly. I hope that helps.

Comment: The question is not about correlating time series, please see the schema.